# How can I grid the mesh circle in geometry nodes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I want to grid the mesh circle like the image in geometry nodes.

[image: Highlitghted circle in the image]

This is what I already have done:
[image: What I have already done]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *Cone* node and then delete it's sides:

[image]

Comment: This was useful but now it created a lot of triangles connected to a point in the middle. Do you know how to fix? https://imgur.com/a/ZNKBan5

Comment: @RenatoRubensSousadosSantos If you don't want to have triangles, just switch the *Fill Type* to "N-Gon".

Answer (score 7):

This is maybe a bit OTT for this one, but it's something I've been working on anyway..

Here's a *Grid Fill* GN group.

The illustrations may be a bit big to be useful.. but I'll try to summarize the method:

[image]

The job of the above sub-group is **1**: to return the indices at the ends of rows and columns for each point in a given grid: e.g. (3,45) in X, (14,20) in Y, for point 17, below. **2**: to associate each point in the perimeter with numbers in a continuous loop:

[image]

That group is used in a 'Basic Grid Fill':

[image]

.. which sends the perimeter of the grid to the target edge-loop, using the indices generated by (**2**, above), and interpolates the locations of the inner vertices between the new locations of their row and column ends. (**1**, above) .

The final *Grid Fill* group adds an interface, exposing an 'Offset', which rotates the grid with respect to the target loop, and 'Span Bias', which allows you to select any of the ratios of X and Y in the grid, having the right number of vertices in its perimeter.

[image]

This shows those parameters being adjusted

[image]

Further work could be done making the sigmoid bias in interpolation (currently provided by *Map Range* 's  'Smooth Step') more controllable. I doubt very much it's unbreakable; if anyone wants to use it, and breaks it, please leave a comment.

[image]

Comment: I would like to understand this. I am beginner at geometry nodes.

Answer (score 6):

just create a mesh circle with 4 vertices, then subdivide:

[image]

[image]

Note: you might want to adapt the radius a bit ;)