# Blender grid fill a edge loop with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm followed this tutorial on youtube in order to create an eye in blender with geometry nodes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TxZBbq8BMA&t=829s&ab_channel=MaxEdge

However, I would like to give it my own twist. Instead of adding the cornea as a seperate isoSphere like in the tutorial, I am extruding edges in order to create the cornea as follows:

[image]

Now I am struggling with trying to fill the geometry at the end of the cornea (most left side of the image).

CG Cookie used a grid fill in order to fill this part of the geometry in the following tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcHX4AT1vtg&t=633s&ab_channel=CGCookie

His geometry looks like this:

[image]

I would like to achieve the same result with geometry nodes, however I do not know how. The following thread tries to answer a similar question: [How can I grid the mesh circle in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269521/how-can-i-grid-the-mesh-circle-in-geometry-nodes)

However, the first 2 answers do not seem to work for me, and I find the third answer to be a bit to complex to test myself.

Could someone try to explain to me how to achieve this result with geometry nodes?

EDIT:

This is the overview of the geometry node that I am working with. It works on a slightly modified uvsphere which can be replicated by watching the first 1 minute and 30 seconds of the first video I mentioned.

[image]

PupilNode:

[image]

IrisNode:
[image]

Cornea Node (The one that I would like to adjust)
[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "do not seem to work for me"? did you try it? what was the result? and maybe share your blend file so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So the first answer in that post results in a cylinder shape, but I would like to have a grid shape. The second answer is a grid shape, but because of the subdivision I do not get an equal amount of vertices (I need 32).

Comment: I will make my project a bit more readable and then upload it