# Geometry Nodes Displace Grid On Curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am currently working with geometry nodes in Blender. I have a circle edge loop that needs to be gridfilled. [image]

I currently have a seperate grid. The vertices inside the circle equals to the vertices on the outer edges on the grid and I would like to displace all the vertices so that they fit inside the circle. Can anyone explain to me how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to create a subdivided cylinder? https://i.imgur.com/sj8xqqs.png https://i.imgur.com/iQq83mK.png

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not trying to make a cylinder, I am trying to fill the circle on the left with a grid like structure

Comment: Do you know about the "grid fill" operator?  https://i.imgur.com/MYKSs3D.png Is this what you're after, or do you want to just carve out a circle out of a grid? https://i.imgur.com/N7bLTRD.png

Comment: Hi Markus, Yes, I am after the gridfill operator! It is available in normal blender, but not with geometry nodes

Comment: If you look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269742/35559), you'll find a 'Grid Fill' GN group which follows the Grid Fill operator very closely, and will fill your circle exactly as the operator does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'Grid Fill' GN group from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269742/35559) to make the transition from grid to circle, or any other shape with the same vertex-count in the perimeter:

[image]

(Depending on what you need, you could expose the Mix factor to the interface of a regrouping of your own)..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to implement it myself first but failed, after i just copied that group it worked

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe that simple trick could do...

Comment: Well this does seem to give the right shape, although with this grid I do not have the right amount of vertices. How would I connect this grid to a different circle then? This grid is in the middle of the scene, like the one in my picture, but i would like to know how to connect these properly

Comment: In my opinion, it would be something like my edited answer

Comment: It's defenitely a step in the right direction, although for me, all the vertices seem to go only to a few places on the circle, so it's not really working properly

Comment: FWIW, the vertices connect like a star

Comment: While this seems to answer the question, perhaps you could add some details about how/why this works as a solution.

Comment: The grid and the circle must be almost the same size and position